# entity framework : combobox in a datagridview fails to use a PK

Tags: entity-framework, datagridview, combobox, foreign-key-relationship

using **EntityFramework**, I have this very simple database model consisting in 2 tables:

```
CustomerType : Id (PK), description  [Id integer]
Customer : Id(PK), CustType, name    [id,custtype are integers]
```

CustType is a foreign key referencing CustomerType.Id

now in a form, I have that datagridview bound to Customer.
First cell is free text to fill up Customer.Name 
second is a combobox (theCellComboBox) bound to CustomerType.description to display all possible customer types:

To do so, I dragged and dropped the Customer entity from the datasource window so that it automatically generated the bindingNavigator UI as well as the datagridview. 
It ended in adding the customerBindingSource, customerBindingNavigator and customerTypeBindingSource in the form designer.

The only code I added is in the constructor of the form where I have this:

```
public FCustomer()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  customerBindingSource.DataSource = context.Customers;
  customerBindingSource.AddingNew += new System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventHandler(AddingNew);
  customerBindingSource.CurrentChanged += new System.EventHandler(CurrentChanged);

  customerDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

  customerBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(SaveItem_Click);
  customerBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Enabled = true;

  theCellComboBox.DataSource = context.CustomerTypes;
  theCellComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
  theCellComboBox.DisplayMember = "description";
}
```

Now the first thing I do when the form open is to add a new entry in the datagrid view by pression the "+" sign on the navigator. I line gets inserted in the datagrid view and the drop down is populated with my customer types.
I choose one of them then click on the name cell.

It crashes instantly with:

```
Exception   {"Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'FMSW_CRM.CustomerType'."}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.
Can someone give guidance please ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you please post more code?  Your binding for the `DataGridView` and the entire method for binding the `ComboBox` will help.